# Two and a sub string

Tags: java, performance, strings, programming-challenge

**Challenge:**

> Given two strings, A and B. Find if there is a substring that appears
>   in both A and B.

**Specifications:**

> Several test cases will be given to you in a single file. The first
>   line of the input will contain a single integer T, the number of test
>   cases.
>
> Then there will be T descriptions of the test cases. Each description
>   contains two lines. The first line contains the string A and the
>   second line contains the string B.
>
> For each test case, display YES (in a newline), if there is a common substring.
>   Otherwise, display NO.

**Implementation:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TwoStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); i> 0; i--) {
            String sub1 = toDiscreteString(input.nextLine());
            String sub2 = toDiscreteString(input.nextLine());
            boolean success;
            if (sub1.length() < sub2.length()) {
                success = hasCommonSubString(sub1, sub2);
            } else {
                success = hasCommonSubString(sub2, sub1);
            }
            System.out.println(success ? "YES" : "NO");
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasCommonSubString(String shorter, String longer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length(); i++) {
            if (longer.indexOf(shorter.charAt(i)) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static String toDiscreteString(String input) {
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (set.add(input.charAt(i))) {
                result.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This is a challenge found on HackerRank and passes all test cases. Is there a more efficient method? Is this overly-convoluted? Java 8 is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Improve encapsulation

This piece of code inside `main` is a bit unfortunate:

> ```
> boolean success;
> if (sub1.length() < sub2.length()) {
>     success = hasCommonSubString(sub1, sub2);
> } else {
>     success = hasCommonSubString(sub2, sub1);
> }
> ```

The `main` method has an almost straightforward nice flow:

1. parse input
2. get result
3. print result

But only *almost*, because the code snippet above breaks it, by mixing in some logic.

It would be better if `hasCommonSubString` encapsulated all of the logic.
Currently the logic is split between two places:

- The main logic is inside `hasCommonSubString`
- The logic of ordering the parameters by length is inside `main`

The problem with this split becomes obvious when you try to write test cases for the method.

Consider this alternative:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); i> 0; i--) {
        String s1 = toDiscreteString(input.nextLine());
        String s2 = toDiscreteString(input.nextLine());
        boolean success = hasCommonSubString(s1, s2);
        System.out.println(success ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}

private static boolean hasCommonSubString(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
        return hasCommonSubStringHelper(s1, s2);
    }
    return hasCommonSubStringHelper(s2, s1);
}
```

I also renamed the variables `sub1`, and `sub2`, as "sub" seems to suggest sub-strings, but these are really just simply strings.

#### Improve performance

It's a pity to convert a `String` to a `Set<Character>` and then convert that back to `String`, to perform \$O(n)\$ lookups on it.
You could just use the `Set<Character>`, no need to convert that to `String`, and that will allow \$O(1)\$ lookups.

Also note that you don't need to convert both parameters. One of them is enough. You can iterate over the other one in a single pass.

Lastly, instead of the repeated `.charAt` calls in this code,
it would be better to save in a local variable and reuse:

> ```
> if (set.add(input.charAt(i))) {
>     result.append(input.charAt(i));
> }
> ```

Comment: Considering that the range of characters is only about 65,000 or even 256 wide, you could even use a [`BitSet`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead of a `Set<Character>`. It carries much less overhead for insertion and calculating the "disjointness" is extremely cheap with `#intersects()`.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing `indexOf` is O(n). A faster way may be to add all the characters of a string to a set. Then call contains for each character of the second string (I would imagine that contains is on average O(1) for a hash set or O(lg(n)) for a tree set.)

```
private static boolean hasCommonSubString(String shorter, String longer)  
{

    Set<Integer> set = shorter.chars()
                              .boxed()
                              .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return longer.chars().anyMatch(set::contains);    
}
```